# Android: something is using up all my wifi

Tags: wi-fi

This is the problem I have, and it just started today. When I start my wifi, everything seems alright. I can use the internet. Then, something kicks off that uses up all the wifi, and at that point, nothing works.

Based on what's happening in the apps, it looks like all of their requests are timing out. The icon shows that I'm constantly uploading/downloading, despite their being no apps on.

I've turned it on and off multiple times to no avail.

What could be doing this? How can I track it down?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen in Safe Mode?  If not then you have an application, that is configured in your normal boot configuration, using all your resources.  You can use something like AutoRuns to determine which application it is.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you set the wifi on the device to "off" then "on" again? Is there a "login" page when connecting to that wifi? (Like what you would see at a hotel or airport?) - Finally, is there issues with any other devices?

Comment: @NBN-Alex this is not a hotel or airport wifi. There's no login. It's my work wifi. Nothing has changed there. No issues on any other devices.

Comment: @Ramhound I rebooted in safemode, and it looks like my wifi is still being used non-stop. Now, it's showing the synching icon as well.

Comment: @Summitch do you have access to your router's login page? If so you can login to the portal and look at connected devices on your wifi tab and it should show you signal %.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove no, I don't currently have access to my router. I'm at work.

Comment: @Summitch So this is not your wifi network? If so many devices could be using the wifi for a multitude of different things, many of which can slow the wifi network down.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove This is a business wifi. It's most certainly not the issue. What I'm pointing out is that it's not just my Wifi is slow on my device. It's that my device shows the Wifi in constant use. It's also heating up. It's like it's working really, really hard on something that's using the network, but nothing should be on.

Comment: Would you be able to post a screenshot of the data usage screen and the Running Processes tab?  There's so many possible answers but I'm thinking it's possible there's a sync of something in progress

Comment: @Summitch download a network analyzer like this: http://www.techet.net/netanalyzer/ and it should possibly show what's using the wifi.